# ESlint ignoring rule

Tags: vue.js, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I'm VERY new to ESLint, but I love the possibilities of using it as a tool.  I have a folder in a Vue project that is the base for my project and I've configured linting for it.  When I run it it lints great but I noticed one rule I didn't like was `comma-dangle`.  After reading about it in their documentation I found what I thought was the correct rule so I opened my `.eslintrc.js` file and added the rule.  My config file now looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    "extends": "airbnb-base",
    "rules": {
        "comma-dangle": ["error", "never"]
    }
};
```

But when I save a file in my project (specifically my `src/main.js` or `router/index.js`) I still get an error that

```
Missing trailing comma
  src/router/index.js:12:28
```

Am I missing something?  I also have a `.eslintignore` file that looks like this:

```
/build/
/config/
/dist/
/*.js
/test/unit/coverage/
```

Comment: Weird, I was playing around with the config file and closed my terminal and reopened, now it seems to be accepting the rule.  Am I suppose to restart my terminal after each change to the config?

Comment: Yes - the dev server does not watch for changes in the config files, it only watches for changes inside your application folder. Unfortunately you have to restart it.